# Transcribe data into a json file keeping its format correct in java

Tags: java, json

My problem is that every time I call the method "public void fileWriter" my data is incorrectly transcribed in the associated JSON file.
In this way it is no longer possible for me to recover them.
What can I do to have the data saved in the correct JSON format?

My method is as follow:

```
public void fileWriter(String name, double temp, double feels_like, double temp_min, double temp_max) throws IOException {
    LocalDateTime myDateObj = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = myDateObj.format(myFormatObj);

    JSONObject citiesObj = new JSONObject();
    citiesObj.put("Call N°", ++cityCounter);
    citiesObj.put("Name", name);
    citiesObj.put("Time", formattedDate);

    JSONObject listOfTemps = new JSONObject();
    listOfTemps.put("temp", temp);
    listOfTemps.put("feels_like", feels_like);
    listOfTemps.put("temp_min", temp_min);
    listOfTemps.put("temp_max", temp_max);

    citiesObj.put("Main"+cityCounter, listOfTemps);

    try {
        File file = new File("FileCities.json");
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("JSON file created:");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("FileCities.json"), true));
        bufferedWriter.write(MessageFormat.format("{0}\n", citiesObj.toJSONString()));
        bufferedWriter.close();     

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        System.out.println("--> File not updated");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While the output of the file is:

```
{"Main1":{"temp":-8.0,"temp_min":-9.0,"feels_like":-8.0,"temp_max":-7.0},"Time":"10-01-2022 14:11:16","Call N°":1,"Name":"Rome"}
{"Main2":{"temp":-9.0,"temp_min":-10.0,"feels_like":-9.0,"temp_max":-9.0},"Time":"10-01-2022 14:11:16","Call N°":2,"Name":"Toronto"}
```

The expected output is:

```
{"Main1":{"temp1":-8.0,"temp_min1":-9.0,"feels_like1":-8.0,"temp_max1":-7.0},"Time1":"10-01-2022 14:11:16","Name1":"Rome", "Main2":{"temp2":-9.0,"temp_min2":-10.0,"feels_like2":-9.0,"temp_max2":-9.0},"Time2":"10-01-2022 14:11:16","Name2":"Toronto"}
```

Comment: Can you add the expected ouput in your question? (Note that your `listOfTemps`variable is not a list)

Comment: I'm not sure of the expected output that you want, but I would look into either manually building out the JSON yourself (which I wouldn't unless required), or using the GSON library. The GSON library will allow you to pass the structure (List, HashMap, etc) into it and will return a JSON string. The even nicer thing is you can load this back into memory by reading the string, again depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. The output I need is: ` {"Main1":{"temp1":-8.0,"temp_min1":-9.0,"feels_like1":-8.0,"temp_max1":-7.0},"Time1":"10-01-2022 14:11:16","Name1":"Rome", "Main2":{"temp2":-9.0,"temp_min2":-10.0,"feels_like2":-9.0,"temp_max2":-9.0},"Time2":"10-01-2022 14:11:16","Name2":"Toronto"}`  I apologize for the banality of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on what your problem is. But in any case I see that you use org.json library, which is very simple but really should be used for learning JSON only. To serialize/de-serialize objects to/from JSON, I would strongly recommend to use Jackson-JSON library or Gson library. However, may I suggest my own library that has a feature that allows you to serialize any object to JSON Stgring and restore it back from that String. The library is called MgntUtils and it has methods:

```
public static <T> T readObjectFromJsonString(java.lang.String jsonString,
                                             java.lang.Class<T> type)
                                      throws java.io.IOException
```

and

```
public static java.lang.String writeObjectToJsonString(java.lang.Object object)
                                                throws com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
```

They are simple for usage. See the Javadoc page for class [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html)

The library you can find both as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.6.0.1/jar) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases), including sources and Javadoc. So you can create any Java class get its instance and write it as a String which you can write into file, Than you can read it back and parse the String as an instance of your your class